# Switch case can't evaluate object property in nested callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback

This function receives an object parameter like {'status': 'info'}, but I can't access it inside some callbacks. Shouldn't it be like a global variable for all the code block?:

```
var msg = {
    status: 'good',
    data: 'cats'
};

function status(msg) {
    console.log(msg.status);
    doSomething(msg.data, function(err, reply) {
        doSomething2(reply, function(err, data) {
            switch(msg.status) { // error: cannot get status of undefined
                case 'info':
                    console.log('Cat info.');
            }
        });
    });
}

function doSomething(data, cb) {
    return 'burdz';
}

function doSomething2(data, cb) {
    return data + ' and dogs';
}

status();
```

Throws an error on accessing the object property of message in the switch case. I can access the property before the doSomething functions, but not inside the last one.

Comment: Most likely, the variable is being overwritten by some code not included in the question. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Use promises!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const msg = {
    status: 'good',
    data: 'cats'
};

function status(msg) {
    console.log(msg.status);
    doSomething(msg.data, function(err, reply) {
        doSomething2(reply, function(err, data) {
            switch(msg.status) {
                case 'info':
                    console.log('Cat info.');
            }
        });
    });
}

function doSomething(data, cb) {
    return 'burdz';
}

function doSomething2(data, cb) {
    return data + ' and dogs';
}

status(msg);
```

You need to pass something to status! Use also const instead of let if your msg is declared in the global state

Interesting lecture about scopes and closures. https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures